# Managing multiple social network logins in firebase in native android

Tags: android, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication, facebook-authentication

I have my main page which is just the same as any other app login main page. It asks for your username and password to login and in case you have are a new user it asks you to sign up. In case the user is new and wants to sign up, my sign up button opens a dialog fragment on top of that login page. There are three sign up buttons in the main login page. Sign up using google, facebook and twitter. All of those three buttons open the same dialog fragment by passing an identifier type. Based on that type, I want to invoke the login class for the respective social network. However I am having some problems with making it work. I want to process the login while displaying a progress dialog but I can't seem to execute the login process in the background without extending any activity. Currently, it opens a separate blank activity and waits for the background login process to complete and then directs you to the home page. How can I do this without extending activity and running it in the background? I have a lot of things to learn. Feel free to point out any mistakes or inefficiencies in my coding.

This is my DialogFragment code snippet

```
dialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
        @Override
        public void onShow(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
            Button getCode = dialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
            getCode.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Log.d("CODE REQUESTED :::: ", "  PLEASE WAIT.....");
                    if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("Phone")) {
                        number = user_ID.getText().toString();
                        code = countryCodePicker.getSelectedCountryCodeWithPlus();
                        finalNumber = code + number;



                        PhoneSignUpProcess phoneSignUpProcess = new PhoneSignUpProcess(context);
                        Intent signUpPhone = new Intent(getActivity(), phoneSignUpProcess.getClass());
                        signUpPhone.putExtra("number", finalNumber.toString());
                        startActivity(signUpPhone);
                        Log.d("Number is :::::   ", finalNumber);
                        dismiss();

                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

And this is my Login Process Class

```
public class PhoneSignUpProcess extends AppCompatActivity {

private Context context;
private DatabaseReference mDatabase;

ProgressDialog dialog;
FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
String number;


public PhoneSignUpProcess(Context c) {
    this.context = c;
}

public PhoneSignUpProcess() {
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    number = getIntent().getStringExtra("number");
    Log.d("Process Number is :::: ", number.toString());
    getCode();

}

PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks callbacks = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
    @Override
    public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
        Log.d("PHONE NUMBER :::::  ", "VERIFIED with credentials  " + phoneAuthCredential);
        signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(phoneAuthCredential);
    }

    @Override
    public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {
        Log.d("EXCEPTION :::::  ", "Exception occurent   " + e);
        Toast.makeText(PhoneSignUpProcess.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCodeSent(String s, PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken) {
        //super.onCodeSent(s, forceResendingToken);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCodeSent:" + s);

        // Save verification ID and resending token so we can use them later
        String mVerificationId = s;
        String token = forceResendingToken.toString();
        Log.d("CODE SENT :::::   ", "ID " + mVerificationId + "\nTOKEN " + token);
    }
};

public void getCode() {
    Log.d("GET CODE NUMBER IS ::: ", number);
    PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(number, 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS, PhoneSignUpProcess.this, callbacks);
}


private void signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {

    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(PhoneSignUpProcess.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                        // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                        Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success");

                        FirebaseUser user = task.getResult().getUser();
                        if (user.getDisplayName() != null) {
                            Toast.makeText(context, "User " + user.getDisplayName() + "created.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                        //updatePassword();

                        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");

                        User newUser = new User();
                        newUser.setPhone(number);

                        String userId = mDatabase.push().getKey();

                        mDatabase.child(userId).setValue(newUser);

                        Intent homeIntent = new Intent(PhoneSignUpProcess.this, Home.class);
                        homeIntent.putExtra("First Login", "true");
                        startActivity(homeIntent);
                    } else {
                        // Sign in failed, display a message and update the UI
                        Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                        if (task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                            // The verification code entered was invalid
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

}

Comment: post your code for more information about how you've implemented it.

Comment: oh ok sure. I will post.